# How to put a list in a GET request?

Tags: json, api, get

I need to build an API from which the user needs to get some information. For this to succeed, I need to supply a list of IDs to the API. Since I want to GET information from the API call I want to keep it a GET request in stead of supplying the list using json through a POST.

As far as I know, the only way of supplying a variable to an API, is to do it like this:

```
http://api.example.com/somecall/?a=1&b=2&c3
```

But that gives every ID a separate variable, instead of making it a list.

So my question is: is it possible to supply a list of IDs to a GET API, like I would normally do in json using `[1,5,3,77,53,8]`?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You should hit the url like this

```
http://api.example.com/somecall/?a=1,2,3
```

And when use $_GET['a'] it will input 1,2,3 and then explode this like that

```
$explode = explode(',',$_GET['a']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `?a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3`.
now `a` is an array